# Python NCBIWWW (Hanging Load)

Tags: python, bioinformatics, freeze, biopython, ncbi

Good Evening StackOverflow Pham,

I'm attempting to use Biopython's functionality for NCBIWWW to find quick <750 protein-peptide alignments. The problem I'm bumping into seems to be a hanging load when launching my program. See my code below:

```
import Bio
from Bio import Seq
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# Use filedialog to locate txt file for query
protein_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(protein_file)

# Parse the txt file, opening and read to VERIFY grab
protein_file = open(protein_file)
protein_read = protein_file.read()
print(protein_read)

# Take query and run to determine homologous alignments of like proteins
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastp", "nt", protein_read)
result_handle = result_handle.open('r')
print(result_handle)
```

Once I run the program (Ctrl + Shift + F10), the first time **IT WORKED!** But now, it just hangs for hours. To solve this, I begun reading through the Biopython Cookbook to find out why my code wasn't working. Here is what I tried.

1. Verify Syntax
2. Rewrite Code

I've attached a screenshot to hopefully provide further context... but I'm genuinely lost.

[image: Screenshot of my Pycharm on infinite HANG]

Any suggestions?

Thank you SO Team!

~ D

Comment: Do you have any idea _where_ it's hanging?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be hanging during the initial query during the NCBIWWW command. It just sits there for hours at a time when the same exact query pulled a result.

Comment: "nt" is a nucleotide db, you should use a protein db like "nr"

Comment: @Chris_Rands, 

This appears to have worked. I was able to get a result within about 2-3 minutes on the largest protein I have (Tape Measure). Thank you so much for your guidance. I will be sure to check for the small syntax next time before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is found from @Chris_Rands

Problem Found - Calling database of "nt" should be database "nr"

Closing request!

Comment: @Dharman I would argue it's not a typo, but actually a conceptual misunderstanding, and the answer remains valid. Do you understand the bioinformatics Q&A?

Comment: @chris Maybe you are right. However, both question and answer are low quality and need serious editing before reopening.